# Need byte count from folder using cmd within python

Tags: python, cmd, size, directory

I have a program that checks folder sizes and adds them all up. I've included the function I'm using. I should mention that win32com.client cannot handle some of the folder size (150gb +).

```
# Calculate Folder Size
# ---------------------

def calc_folder_size(dir):
    fso = com.Dispatch("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    folder = fso.GetFolder(dir)
    MB=1024*1024.0
    try:
        return (folder.Size/MB)    
    except:
        statinfo = os.stat(dir)
        return (statinfo.st_size/MB)
```

os.stat only gives the size of a file, is there an equivalent for folders (and sub-folders)?

Cheers

Comment: What about `glob`bing your way through all the files in the dir?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def get_tree_size(path):
    """Return total size of all files in directory tree at path."""
    return sum(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, filename))
               for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
               for filename in files)
```

Comment: I was using os.walk before and it was painfully slow. The database is about 15TB.

Comment: then you should ask: how I speed up `get_tree_size()`. Try [`scandir`](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) that returns both whether the entry is a file (not directory) and its size in a single call (it should be several times faster).

Comment: Sad part is that the win32com.client covers a slightly smaller folder in 2 minutes. The get_tree_size() has already taken 8 minutes.

Comment: do you use this [`get_tree_size()`](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir/blob/master/benchmark.py#L115)? Note: if you directories may be deeply nested then rewrite it to be non-recursive.

Comment: I did, and it is painfully slow. Not really a viable solution. DOS gets byte counts very quickly, I feel there must be a way to extract this within python. (Sorry for any silly comments, I'm not a programmer by trade)

Comment: It is suspicious. What results do you get if you run [`benchmark.py -s -r non-existing-dir`](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir/blob/master/benchmark.py)? Could you add [`"Scripting.FileSystemObject"`-based `get_tree_size()`](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir/blob/master/benchmark.py#L128) to the comparison?

Comment: Mr. Sebastian. Your solution ALMOST works. It fails on one of my files and I can't figure out why haha. Thanks for your help though.